# Releasing memory reserved by std::vector and its elements in descrutor of class that holds it

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, vector, stl

I would like to know if I should manually release the memory reserved by `std::vector` and its elements in the destructor of the class that contains that vector. And if so - how exactly?

**Situation #1 - std::vector of primitive types:**

```
class A{
    std::vector<int> elements;
    A(){...}
};
```

**Situation #2 - std::vector of complex types:**

```
class B{
    int b;
    C * pointer;
    ...
};

class A{
    std::vector<B> elements;
    A(){...}
};
```

**Situation #3 - std::vector of pointers to complex types:**

```
class B{
    int b;
    C * pointer;
    ...
};

class A{
    std::vector<B*> elements;
    A(){...}
};
```

In which cases the destructor of A should be empty? In which it should look like:

```
A::~A(){
    for(auto &e : elements){
        delete e;
    }
    elements.clear();
}
```

I think about situation, when `elements` belongs only to `A` and are not shared by any other structure (**when `A` is destroyed, the `elements` should also be destroyed**).

**It seems obvious that for `std::vector` of pointers, I have to use `delete e` on each element**.

But:

1. Do I really have to call `elements.clear();` (the object will be destroyed after that line - isn't it waste of instructions)?
2. Maybe I should also use `erase(...)` method of `std::vector` in loop? **If so**, wouldn't `clear()` make all the work for me instead (when the `std::vector` does not contains pointers)?

Did I miss something? **What's the best approach?**

p.s. Situation #3 is about pointers and **not a shared pointers**.

Comment: `It seems obvious that for std::vector of pointers, I have to use delete e on each element. `  Really?  `std::vector<int*> iv; int x; iv.push_back(&x);`  Call `delete` and watch the sparks fly.

Comment: The rule is simple -- std::vector knows how to remove its own dynamically allocated memory that it uses to manages its internal array.  If your class creates its own dynamically allocated memory, you're responsible for cleaning that up.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I believe you did not read the question carefully enough. Read the situation #3 description (bold): "std::vector of pointers to complex types". `int` is not a complex type.

About the second comment: you postulate that in each situation empty destructor for A will be fine, am I right? Of course excluding the `delete e`.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the type is "complex" or not. I can easily create a "complex" type as a global or on the stack, and stick the address of it in your vector. Maybe that's the answer to your question in a roundabout way -- a vector has no way to know where that pointer comes from or what type of memory it points to, so it can't possibly "delete" it by issuing a `delete` call.

Comment: Ok, I missed the situation when you use it in a wrong way. But push_back(&member) should be avoided in my situation (also, `elements` are private so such thing could occur only inside of A). My purpose of `vector<Type*>` was to store pointers to dynamically allocated objects (in other case, I could use `vector<Type>`), created with `new` attribute - sorry for not specify it from start.

Comment: Why don't you use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<my_type>>` instead? No headaches left. (The `vector` destroys all its elements on being destroyed. Whether they have pseudo-dtors, trivial dtors or complex ones.)

Comment: @Deduplicator I knew somebody will bring up shared pointers, std::unique_ptr even when I post "it's not a question about shared pointers". Both pointers and shared pointers exist in C++ and have their pros & cons. The discussion about superiority of shared pointers in not a subject of that question.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Can you make an answer from your second comment? I guess I can accept it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I would like to know if I should manually release the memory reserved by `std::vector` and its elements in the destructor of the class that contains that vector.

No, you never need to do that. Like any well designed RAII type, standard containers automatically destroy their contained objects when they are erased from the container (which includes erasing all the elements by destroying the container).

> It seems obvious that for std::vector of pointers, I have to use `delete e` on each element.

Only if you're abusing the pointers to imply ownership of the objects they point to. We have smart pointers to make the ownership explicit, and automatically delete the objects at the right time.

> Do I really have to call `elements.clear();`

No, the destructor will take care of that.

> Maybe I should also use `erase(...)` method of `std::vector` in loop?

No, that would be even worse. It would invalidate the iterator used by the loop, giving undefined behaviour. The destructor will erase all the elements for you.

> What's the best approach?

Store objects when you can. If you need pointers, store smart pointers if you want the container to "own" the objects, or regular pointers (or perhaps weak pointers) if you're managing the objects in some other way and just want the container to refer to them.

Comment: Thanks for the step-by-step answer. However I have to mention that in some specific cases I use regular pointers and have reasons to use them instead of smart ones - but it's off topic, I guess. Once again, thanks for clear answer.

Comment: @PolGraphic: Whatever those reasons are, they lead to unmaintainable code littered with memory leaks and worse, for no benefit. Think again about whether they are good reasons, then use smart pointers anyway.

Comment: If there are no benefits, there would be no reasons. I doubt you can assume that not knowing them. And for sure, it does not simply "lead to code with memory leaks" - it "lead to code that `can` have memory leaks" at best (I partly agree). I believe we should not continue the discussion about pointers vs smart pointers as it's quite off topic for that question. Let's keep it simple.

Comment: Indeed, feel free to ignore me if you're convinced by these "reasons". You asked for "the best approach", so my advice stands.